# Algorithm for selecting representative samples from a group of data points, so that the main features of the data are preserved

Tags: algorithm, optimization, selection

**Problem:**

In short, this is a multi-criterion sample selection problem. I have a bunch of data (from physical samples), from which I want to select a smaller bunch, so that I can run some expensive experiments. All data are categorized by different classification schemes (A, B, C, etc.). For example, sample x is in group 1 based on classification scheme A, group 3 based on classification scheme B and so on. Each classification scheme can result in different number of classes.

Ideally, I would want to:

- Have selected samples cover all classes. For example, I want samples
  belonging to group A1 to cover groups B1, B2, etc.; C1, C2, etc. and
  so on. And similarly, samples in (say) C2 to cover all classes of A
  and B.… You get the gist! In addition, being able to have samples
  belonging to A1 and B1 to cover all C classes (and other similar
  deeper coverages) would be favorable. Remember that I said, ideally!
- Have selected samples minimize an error. This error is defined by how
  well some plots for “all samples” and “selected samples” match. Think
  of it as an objective function that I can define.

**What I have done:**

I have thought of 6 algorithms to select samples, which are mostly special-purpose cases of a main algorithm. Here’s a summary of the main algorithm:

1. Significance factors are assigned to each classification scheme (A, 
   B, C, etc.) by the user.
2. Weight factors are assigned to each individual class (1, 2, 3, etc.),
   by default based on the relative number of samples that the class
   holds.
3. A specific total weight is calculated for each sample, given the
   different classes it is assigned to.
4. Simple selection algorithms (Roulette, Rank and Tournament) are used
   to select the samples based on their weights. The seed of the random
   number generator (used for the three selection algorithms) is
   optimized with Genetic Algorithm so that the previously-defined
   objective function is minimized.

**What I expect from writing this:**

I would really appreciate any pointers on whether:

- my way of approaching the problem has any major drawbacks or can be
  improved;
- there is any standard method or algorithm for this.

Comment: How large is the pool of data you have and how large should the selection be (in number of samples)? Also, can you provide an as-accurate-as-possible upper bound on the number of groups&schemes and a lower bound on the number of samples you assume will get into a group? In some cases, you might just need to pick samples uniformly at random from the initial pool. While this won't minimize the errors you were talking about, it might get you really close to what you need (with basically no effort).

Comment: • All data: 200-500;

• Selected data: 40-100;

• Number of schemes: typically 4-6; but actually 1 to infinity (custom schemes).

• Number of groups for each scheme: 2-10;


• Number of samples in each group: It is actually 0 to all samples. But the typical values should be 0 to half the number of all samples.
 
Please do note that none of the above numbers are a “must”. The nature of the work leaves many of these numbers to the discretion of users. 

Simple random selection is an option. However, representativeness (low error) is indispensable and too much randomness is not favorable at all.